# web element inspector (safari / chrome) dimmed css properties

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, properties, web-inspector

Silly web element inspector (safari / chrome) question, but I can't seem to figure out why some properties are dimmed.

[image: element inspector]

Comment: Have ye a link of liveness to refer to?

Comment: an example: http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/ and inspect the 'browse all features' button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to source Webkit inspector apply 50% opacity to css styles that are "inherited" or "implicit", from [inspector.css](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/inspector/front-end/inspector.css&q=inspector&exact_package=chromium&d=6&l=4216)

```
.styles-section .properties .implicit, .styles-section .properties .inherited {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

- Implicit are the one that are under a composite property like `border: 1px solid red` `color: red` will be grayer.
- Inherit are the ones with the explicit "inherit" value.

Now the current chrome version seem to color gray some other values, too bad the inspector on the inspector is not working anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

After looking at it on the link you provided, the faded (dimmed) ones are the style rules that don't have any browser operations linked to them, for example:

Click the little arrow next to `background:` you get a list of rules that Chrome uses to interpret your CSS.

On `float` and `height`, there is pretty much only one way that can be interpreted and so Chrome doesn't need to add any browser specific styles to make it display as intended.

Hope that helps to explain it :)

Faded rules are rules that don't need any special attention from the browser :)

Comment: It seems to be something else. On the apple website the float:left; property is dimmed / faded. When you go to http://webkit.org/ and inspect the 'download nightly build' button the float right property isn't dimmed / faded.

Comment: Well that is an interesting one.. It could possibly be corrected tags? But I doubt that.

Comment: I have no idea, I have been digging around as much as I can on the internet for the past hour and can't come up with anything. I would love to know the reasons behind this faded css rules!!

Comment: I'm seeing this on a lot of rules that clearly do have an effect, like `float:left`. Unchecking the box to remove the rule changes things, so I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just a charset mixing problem.

The HTML file itself and one of the CSS files were encoded as UTF-8 with BOM, while other CSS file was encoded as ANSI. I still cannot figure out how Chrome managed to show almost everything right. I switched all of the files back to UTF-8 without BOM and the problem was solved. Thanks to the W3C validator that hinted me on the presence of the BOM.

Hope this helps at least someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you also getting "interpreted as image but transferred with mime type text/css" ?
I was.

This solved it:
[Chrome interprets CSS Stylesheet as image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182762/chrome-interprets-css-stylesheet-as-image)

Basically, if your css file has 'background: url()' or 'background: url("")' in it, just comment them out or delete them (or you know, just put a path in there)
The page should then load with the css styles in chrome inspector back as active.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - but did you check if it ain't just a way to easily distinguish computed styles?