# Chrome interprets CSS Stylesheet as image

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, http-headers

In my CodeIgniter website, when viewed in Chrome, the console shows a warning

`style.css interpreted as IMAGE but transferred with MIME type text/css`

The page renders as I expect it to, but when I right-click and inspect any element, it's 'computed styles' shows up as blank, making debugging difficult.

This is how I'm serving my CSS file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>        
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?= base_url('assets/images/favicon.png'); ?>" />       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?= base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
```

using a Chrome extension, I monitored the header's being sent when I request style.css, and this is what I get:

[image]

**EDIT**

This is on a LAMP server on a shared godaddy host. My overriding htaccess only contains the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is it just chrome? or does it happen with all browsers?

Comment: Firefox (with firebug) is able to compute styles normally when I inspect an element. Even Chrome with Firebug works fine. It's only Chrome native inspector that seems to have a problem.

Comment: Try adding this to your .htaccess
`AddType text/css .css`

Comment: This happens with my projects on chrome too. I have no idea why it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely caused by an invalid relative path inside of the css file.

For instance *in html* a similar message could be reproduced by adding `<img src="" />` which will be parsed as a relative path and resolve as *current_page_url* - prompting a "...but transferred with MIME type text/html" error.

Comment: I commented out every single instance where I was using a path in my CSS file (mostly just `background-image`s), but still same problem.

Comment: @xbonez: I've done some more searching and came across [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/658238/1081234) confirming my suspition. Are you able to reproduce the issue in jsfiddle and if so, can you share the code?

Comment: This fixed up my shiz - doing dev on a local wamp install.